# How can this sum sign be expanded?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can this sum sign

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\log (n)} 2^i$$

be expanded to

$$2^{\log (n)+1}-2$$

Which rules do I need to look at to understand this?

Comment: Sum of geometric sequence

Comment: $2+4=8-2,2+4+8=16-2,2+4+8+16=32-2,2+4+8+16+32=64-2$, no ? What's the pattern ?

Comment: Two steps needed here: (1) Forget about $\log(n)$ - call it a $k$ and, if you know how to calculate $\sum_{i=1}^k2^i$ for *any* $k$, you will know how to do it if $k=\log(n)$. (2) Now to the problem of calculating $\sum_{i=1}^k2^i$ - this is the sum of a *geometric sequence* - are you familiar with those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the formula for the geometric sum. The terms follow a geometric progression, first term $a = 2^1 = 2$, common ratio $ r = 2$ and number of terms $N = \log n$ (assuming $\log n$ is a positive integer, obviously).

$S_N = \frac{a(r^n - 1)}{r-1} = \frac{2(2^{\log n} - 1)}{2 - 1} = 2^{\log n + 1} - 2$

Answer (score 1):

In binary,

$$1+10+100+1000+10000=11111=100000-1.$$

You can generalize.

Answer (score 0):

You can show $S_m=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m 2^i = 2^{m+1}-2$ by induction or as a geometric series.

For example $2S_m=\sum\limits_{i=2}^{m+1} 2^{i}$ and $S_m=2S_m-S_m = 2^{m+1}-2^1$

Then substitute $m= \log(n)$ to get $S_{\log(n)}$, at least when $\log(n)$ is an integer

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the other responses.  In my opinion, absent any agreed convention on how to perform the summation when the upper bound is not an integer, the summation is **gibberish**.

Suppose that you regard $f(i) = 2^i.$  In order to evaluate the summation, first you have to clearly express it as the sum of terms.  For example, $f(1) + f(2) + \cdots + f(k)$ or $f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + \cdots$ [re when the upper bound is $\infty$].

Only **after** the summation is clearly expressed as the sum of terms can you then try to simplify the expression.  To try to simplify the expression without a clear summation is simply putting the cart before the horse so that you can ignore that the summation is gibberish.

It may well be that there exists an already agreed upon convention that would allow the summation to be evaluated as other responses have.  However, prior to this query, I (for one) have never seen such a convention anywhere.

My total ignorance of such a convention should have *some* relevance.  How will math students react?  Is the OP's puzzlement really so surprising?